# How to implement a join for getting count of all records in 2nd table prior to a date that is specified in a column of 1st table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two tables let's call them users, events

```
users: [user_id, activity_date]
       [123,     4-28-2020    ]
       [456,     4-27-2020    ]

events: [user_id, event_date]
       [123,     5-28-2020    ]
       [456,     4-27-2020    ]
       [456,     4-25-2020    ]
       [456,     4-30-2020    ]
       [456,     1-30-2020    ]
       [123,     1-28-2020    ]
```

I'd like to get a rollup table that shows for each user the count of events in the events table prior to the value stored in users.activity_date.

So the above example would yield:

```
[user_id, total]
[123,       1  ]
[456,       3  ]
```

I'm a bit confused how to write this, I know I need to join on the user_id, then filter the values for activity_date within events based on the activity_date value specified... Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Columns activity_date and event_date data types?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method is a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*,
       (select count(*)
        from events
        where e.user_id = u.user_id and e.event_date < u.activity_date
       ) as events_before
from users u;
```

An alternative method uses window functions and a cumulative sum:

```
select u.*, e.cnt
from users u left join
     (select e.*,
             lead(event_date) over (partition by user_id order by event_date) as next_event_date,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by event_date) as cnt
      from events e
     ) e
     on u.user_id = e.user_id and
        u.activity_date >= e.event_date and
        (u.activity_date < e.next_event_date or e.next_event_date is null);
```

This is not exactly the same logic.  It counts an event that occurs at exactly the same time (so it is not "strictly before".  Also, things get tricky if events are at exactly the same time.

Both of these can be fixed, but they complicate the logic, so I'm sticking with this.

Comment: Unfortunately this method doesn't work -- it ends up being very slow as I have many users and millions of events.

Comment: @user491880 . . . I added an alternative approach that is more Redshift compatible.